# Call function by pointer in C#

Tags: c#, pointers

I trying to call a function of an other running process by pointer in C# but unfortunately i don't find the answer for it.
The memory address of the function is always the same.

In C++ i can do this:

```
#define DefinedMemoryAddress 0x123456
struct someStruct
{
  int someInt;
  float someFloat;
}

int main()
{
  someStruct createdStruct = ...;
  ( (void (_stdcall*)(someStruct*)) DefinedMemoryAddress)( createdStruct );
}
```

Somebody can help me with a C# version of it?

Comment: Can you provide more details, are you trying to call a function of a unmanaged dll ([P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx)) or are you trying to do dll [hooking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking) of a running process, or something else entirely?

Comment: Windows gives each process its own address space.  This cannot possibly work.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can try Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer to obtain delegate from pointer

Comment: I want to call a method from a running process. The method always have the same address, and i know the base address of it so i only have to call it, but i dont know how to do it in C#

Comment: I'm going to save you some time now: If you have c++ code that works, do it in C++/CLI and wrap it in a managed class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to call a method from a running process. The method always have
>   the same address, and i know the base address of it so i only have to
>   call it, but i dont know how to do it in C#

What you are looking for is called [Hooking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking), it is not easy to do in C# itself, in fact you need to use some unmanaged libraries to do it. However, luckily for you, someone wrote all the hard stuff already in a library for you called [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/).

It is not just as simple as the code you posted above (but I doubt your code you posted above would "just work" either), they have a tutorial in the [downloads section](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/releases/view/85599) I recommend you read through to learn how to do it.

---

However all that aside, I highly recommend [the suggestion in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685716/call-function-by-pointer-in-c-sharp/18685893#comment27524886_18685716)

> If you have c++ code that works,
>   do it in C++/CLI and wrap it in a managed class.

Going this approach will be much easier to do than trying to learn how to use something like EasyHook from scratch (if it will even do exactly what you are wanting to do).

Answer (score 0):

Scott's answer is definitely the easier and cleaner solution, but it's worth noting that you can call any pointer as a function pointer in CIL with the [`calli` instruction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.calli.aspx). It is less safe than delegates, and C# doesn't have any built-in way of using the instruction outside of emitting it via reflection, but the benefit is that it is significantly faster than a delegate.

You should only use it when:

1. Your code is time-sensitive
2. You don't know the location of the function at compile time (and can't use P/Invoke, which is faster)

A perfect use-case for this is loading OpenGL extensions, where the function declaration is known, but the location is implementation-specific and is queried at runtime.

This question specifically should be using a hooking library, but if anyone else finds this question based on the title, this may be the answer they're looking for.